# how to change the white color of the img-thumbnail in bootstrap 4 while using in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is the output when I process my code:

[image: output]

I want to make the border of the image to be black. How can I change that ?

```
<section style="background: #dfe6e9;" class="p-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="Profile-pic.jpg" width="500em" class="rounded-circle img-fluid img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: There are no classes in Bootstrap 4 for border width or style. You could try border-dark, however you may have to manually add smth like: "  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: black;  " to either a class or inline " <img src="" style="border-width: 3px;
    border-color: black; " >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add style to the `img` as

```
<section style="background: #dfe6e9;" class="p-3">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="Profile-pic.jpg" width="500em" class="rounded-circle img-fluid img-thumbnail" style = "border: 2px solid #000000">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">


            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can add your own class to the img, or an ID, and just add 
`border: 1px solid black`

Answer (score 1):

well to really achieve what you want, just add some `id` to the picture (so only this one's borded changes) and change `.img-thumbnail`'s `background-color` in additional the css

```
<style>

#my-image.img-thumbnail {
   background-color: black;
}

</style>
```